# Rust: Asymmetry in indexing vector on left and right side of assignment

Tags: vector, rust

Can someone explain the difference between `&v[0]` versus `v[0]` where `v` is a `Vector`? If I were to guess it is similar to "borrowing" versus "moving", however the following examples would suggest a different reason.

1)

> You can access the vector items by referring to the index number:
>
> ```
>     let mut data = vec![5, 10, 15];
>
>     let first = &data[0];
>     println!("The first element is {}", first);
> ```

2. 

> To change the value of a specific item, refer to the index number:
>
> ```
> let mut data = vec![5, 10, 15];
>
> data[0] = 15;
> ```

Why not `&data[0]` in example 2, and the opposite in example 1? Will data be moved if the type inside the vector did not implement `Copy` trait?

PS: I'm coming from C++ background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The square bracket indexing syntax automatically derefs the result returned from the `Index` or `IndexMut` trait. They resolve to the value stored in the data structure, and you have to explicitly reference in order to get a reference instead.

This means your examples desugar to this

```rust
// needed for explicit `index` and `index_mut`
use std::ops::{Index, IndexMut};

let mut data = vec![5, 10, 15];

let first = &{ *data.index(0) }; // first has type `&i32`
println!("The first element is {}", first);

data[0] = 15; // assignment is always done through IndexMut
*data.index_mut(0) = 15;

let mut_ref: &mut i32 = &mut data[i]; // also desugars to IndexMut
let mut_ref: &mut i32 = data.index_mut(i);

let imm_ref: &i32 = &data[i]; // desugars to Index
let imm_ref: &i32 = data.index(i);

let val: i32 = data[i]; // desugars to dereferenced Index
let val: i32 = *data.index(i);
```

For your examples, which use integers (which are a `Copy` type meaning that they can still be used after moves), there's really no reason to take a reference instead of just doing `data[i]` in the first case.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Follow-up question on the last statement of yours; if I do not take a reference to `data[i]`, any updates to the value through the variable will not get reflected in the vector right?

Comment: Yes, it will copy the value from `data[i]`. Worth noting that while holding an immutable reference (`&data[i]`) the value it references can't be modified. And if you hold a mutable reference (`&mut data[i]`) the value can only be modified through that reference.